# Other method Indefinite Integral :$\int \frac{1}{1+x^2} dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

**Question**

> How indefinite integral :
> $$\int \frac{1}{1+x^2}  dx$$

I know this
$$\int \frac{dx}{1+x^2}=\arctan x + C$$

One of my friends in high school studied integration and came across this example. He does not know arctan x and does not know anything about it.  I want to help him answer this question.  My question is, are there other ways to answer this integral?

Comment: $x=\tan t$ substitution :)

Comment: If he doesn't know about $\arctan x$, or inverse trigonometric functions in general, perhaps he should study that _first_ before trying to tackle indefinite integrals involving those functions... :-)

Comment: You really should start using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/) or similar to check if there are any duplicates to your question.

Comment: I came up with another substitution: $x = \sinh t$ :)

Comment: Any other integral of the function $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ will be, up to a constant, the function $\arctan x$. So there's no way to avoid that function.

Comment: Agree with @StackTD: before studying calculus one is to clear up all pre-calculus questions including elementary functions.

Comment: @StackTD Yes, I told him that this integration would be studied at the university level.  This made him feel somewhat frustrated. I am looking for other ways that might be useful to solve this integral.

Comment: If you know complex numbers, you could factor $x^2+1 = (x+i)(x-i)$ and do it by partial fractions.  The answer involves logarithms of complex values.

Comment: @GEdgar To suggest power series expansion would be less painful than complex log.

Comment: @GEdgar Using complex numbers in integration will raise more questions.

Comment: @GEdgar Using complex numbers in integration will raise more questions.

Comment: I don't know why my question was downvoted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By partial fractions,
$$\begin{array}
.\int\frac{dx}{x^2+1}&=\frac{1}{2i}\left(\frac1{x-i}-\frac1{x+i}\right)dx\\
&=\frac1{2i}(\ln(x-i)-\ln(x+i))+C\\
&=\frac1{2i}\ln(\tfrac{x-i}{x+i})+C
\end{array}$$

Comment: Basic knowledge of complex numbers is needed.

Comment: I will accept your answer because I think it is the only way to do it, thanks

Comment: Power series is meaningful only in interval of convergence.

Answer (score 5):

Just horsing around:
$$\int \frac{dx}{1+x^2} = \left\{x = \sinh t\right\} = \int \frac{\cosh t}{\cosh^2t}dt = \int\frac{dt}{\cosh t}=$$
$$\int\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{E_nt^n}{n!}dt = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{E_n}{n!}\int t^n dt=C+\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{E_nt^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} = $$
$$=C+\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{E_{n-1}t^n}{n!}=C + \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{E_{n-1}\sinh^nx}{n!}$$

Comment: Are you serious? Lol.

Comment: @BobDobbs Btw may be a good approach to prove some properties of [Euler numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_numbers)

Comment: Hyperbolic functions and Euler numbers for someone who has never heard of the inverse tangent...?

Comment: @StackTD Sorry, I began to develop the idea of $x=\sinh t$ substitution and decided to publish the results

Comment: I guess it's not a good approach for someone in high school but it's an interesting idea thank you

Answer (score 3):

Substitute $x=\tan t$. Then, $dx = \sec^2 t\ dt$
$$\int\frac1{1+x^2}dx
= \int \frac {\sec^2t}{1+\tan^2t}dt
= \int dt =t +C$$

Comment: I think this is the best